# Multiline axis label with CategoricalAxis in Bokeh?

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, bokeh

I'm working on a Bokeh plot, and have got it almost the way I want it. However, I'm struggling with adding multi-line axis labels.

Here’s what I have so far:

```
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.plotting import gridplot, figure, output_file, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, BoxAnnotation, CategoricalAxis, FactorRange
from bokeh.embed import components

x = ['label1','label2','label3','label4','label5','label6','label7', 'Trying for a multiline label']
y = [1.0, 2.7, 1.2, 4.5, 1.5, 2.2, 1.8, 4.6]
p = figure(x_range=[*x], y_range=(0, 5), plot_height=400, plot_width=550)
dots = p.circle(x=x, y=y, color='black',size=10)
line = p.line(x=x, y=y, color='black')

numbers = [str(x) for x in y]
p.extra_x_ranges = {"extra_numbers": FactorRange(factors=numbers)}
p.add_layout(CategoricalAxis(x_range_name="extra_numbers"), 'below')
p.title.text = 'Plot'
p.title.text_font_size = "25px"
p.title.text_color = "black"
p.title.align = "center"

low_box = BoxAnnotation(top=2, fill_alpha=0.1, fill_color='green')
mid_box = BoxAnnotation(bottom=2, top=3, fill_alpha=0.1, fill_color='orange')
high_box = BoxAnnotation(bottom=3, fill_alpha=0.1, fill_color='red')

p.add_layout(low_box)
p.add_layout(mid_box)
p.add_layout(high_box)

show(p)
```

The above code yields the following plot:
[image]

You can clearly see that the last label didn't wrap properly, and I have not managed to figure our how to make it wrap and create a multi-line axis label. Is there an easy way to do this? The best alternative solution I came up with was trying to use vertical labels, but as you can see, they don’t look very nice, and mess up the second axis below the text:

```
from bokeh.models import CategoricalAxis, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from math import pi

x = ['label1','label2','label3','label4','label5','label6','label7', 'Trying for a multiline label']
y = [1.0, 2.7, 1.2, 4.5, 1.5, 2.2, 1.8, 4.6]
p = figure(x_range=[*x], y_range=(0, 5), plot_height=900)
dots = p.circle(x=x, y=y, color='black',size=10)
line = p.line(x=x, y=y, color='black')
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/2
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "1.4em"

p.xaxis.axis_line_width = 2
p.yaxis.axis_line_width = 2
numbers = [str(x) for x in y]
p.extra_x_ranges = {"extra_numbers": FactorRange(factors=numbers)}
p.add_layout(CategoricalAxis(x_range_name="extra_numbers"), 'below')
show(p)
```

Now the graph looks like this:
[image]

An easy fix is, of course, switching the order of the axes so that the numbers are on top and the labels are below; however, that is still a haphazard solution, and isn't really what I'm going for. I would really like text wrapping in the label. For instance, the plot below is similar to what I want to accomplish (the code for this non-Bokeh graph below can be found [here](https://www.dexplo.org/dexplot/)).
[image]

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiline labels are not possible with the stock Bokeh axes models. In order to achieve this, you'd have to create a custom `Axis` subclass and manage all the wrapping yourself because `canvas` context doesn't support it in any way.

As an alternative, you can try angled labels. A downside of such approach is having to figure out the right offsets of the plot to make sure that the labels are not cut off.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I have alternatives at this point (just using shorter axis names), but I will look into creating a custom `Axis` subclass. Sorry, I'm kind of new to programming - how would I pass the custom subclass in my code to Bokeh's `Axis` so it knows to use the subclass?

Comment: The exact same way you add that secondary X axis. Only you'd have to remove the automatically created one or just create the whole plot manually by using the `Plot` model directly instead of the `figure` function.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-line labels have been working in bokeh since the past couple of releases (Since 3.3, I believe). You need to add new line characters '\n' yourself in appropriate locations in the label strings.